# The usage of "allowed"

Tags: sentence-construction, infinitive-vs-gerund

I was practicing with a key word transformation exercise, and I had trouble with the following sentence:

> Is it possible to smoke in this room?

The key word given is "allow".

> Is __________________ this room?

My choice was this:

> Is it allowed to smoke in this room?

But it led to a mistake. Why was it not correct?

Answer (score 1):

You chose:

> Is it allowed to smoke in this room?

While the meaning is clear enough it's awkward to the point of being wrong.

This makes sense:

> Is it allowed in this room?

But if want to name what 'it' refers to you want to say:

> Is smoking allowed in this room?

Answer (score 0):

> **Is it allowed to smoke in this room?**
>
> **Is smoking allowed in this room?**
>
> **Am I allowed to smoke in this room**
>
> **Is one allowed to smoke in this room?**

Keeping the key aside, All the sentences above seem correct to me.